# Vertical div expansion w/o fixed heights

Tags: html, css

Before you roll your eyes and move on, I know how to solve this problem by using a fixed height and absolution positioning with top: and bottom:, but I want to solve it without using fixed heights. I want to learn more about CSS so I'm trying to solve this a different way.

I have set up a typical navbar running across the top, and then a scrolling content div below.

However! How do I fit the bottom scrolling div container to the remaining space without using absolute coordinates? I can't do position: absolute, because then I'd need to know the height of the navbar to set "top:". And I can't do "bottom: 0" because I'd have to specify a height.

Here's the JS filddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8dugffz4/1/

The class of interest is ".result". I currently have the height fixed, which I don't want.

Thanks, y'all.
PT

CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: Helvetica, Sans;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navBar {
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.pageBar {
  float: right;
}

.pager {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #bbb;
}

.pager:hover {
  background: #777;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}

.fliph {
  -ms-transform:scale(-1,1); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:scale(-1,1); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:scale(-1,1); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:scale(-1,1); /* Opera */
}

.results {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.line {
  height: 10em;
  line-height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class='navBar'>
        <div class='pageBar'>
            <div class='pager'>&#9665;</div>
            <div class='pager'>1</div>
            <div class='pager fliph'>&#9665;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='results'>
        <div class='line'>Line1</div>
        <div class='line'>Line2</div>
        <div class='line'>Line3</div>
        <div class='line'>Line4</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not possible using css. unless fixed height is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `display: table` and can actually achieve fluid heights:

http://jsfiddle.net/8dugffz4/8/

And a minimalistic snippet in case you want to see specifically what I did:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#table {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#table > div {
  display: table-row;
}
#navbar {
  height: 45px;
  opacity: .5;
}
#navbar > div {
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
#results {
  height: 100%;
}
#results > div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
  <div id="navbar">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="results">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I only set the height of the navbar as a placeholder - note that if you remove the height property your navbar will adjust it's height based on the content inside.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you try adding content to #results until it overflows you will see that the navbar scrolls off the page. Even if you add `#result div { overflow: scroll; }` the entire page scrolls, not the content.

Comment: Here - I added `overflow: auto` to `.results > div` and got your original fiddle to work using my `display: table` and `display: table-row` technique: http://jsfiddle.net/8dugffz4/8/

Comment: Thank you, that's a good trick. The rendering rules and precedents of HTML still make my head spin, even without invoking table properties. I'm hoping one day it'll snap into focus for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for an alternative to the `position: absolute` method, you could use the `height: 100%` method:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { box-sizing: border-box; padding-top: 45px; }
.navBar { height: 45px; margin-top: -45px; }
.results { height: 100%; }
```

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/8dugffz4/7/

Comment: Ah, but this one requires fixing the height of the navbar to 45px. That's what I'm trying to avoid! I want the navBar div to fit to its contents. However, box-sizing is new to me so I will play around with that. Thanks.